# PHP file writing does not work

Tags: php, html, file

So, I've got a piece of code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("\\sid-win-file02\Summer_Students\ASName.Surname", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

This is PHP code and in theory it should create a file in the directory `\\sid-win-file02\Summer_Students\ASName.Surname` but it does not.

From what I understand, it should throw an error if it is unable to, but it does not.
Could someone help?

I tried using a different method, w+, but it changed nothing.

I am new to PHP.

*Note:* I am trying to save the file on a local server. I do techinally have the permission to.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add `<?php  error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and remove \\ form `fopen("\\sid-win-file02\Summer_Students\ASName.Surname", "w")`

Comment: Also use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `\\` , cause it wont work on linux. If directory doesn't exist it won't work.

Comment: Paths starting with \\ are Windows UNC paths and will only work on windows

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is an escape character. You should double them or use forward slashes instead.

Also, \\sid-win-fil‌​e02 is probably an issue. Use a relative path instead.

Comment: Paths starting with \\ are Windows UNC paths, there is no way for specifying those relatively.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the directory `\\sid-win-file02\Summer_Students` exists and is writable